# generate url inside view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

What I need is to generate the full url for one of my controllers inside a view (so that a user can copy it).
For the following:

```
    [GET("invitationrequest/create")]
    public ActionResult Execute()
    {
```

I need to generate something like: http://xyz.com/invitationrequest/create

I've seen this answer: [Getting full URL of action in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005367/getting-full-url-of-action-in-asp-net-mvc) - it does the job, but only if the view and the controller have the same path.
The problem is in my case, the view sits in a different location - let's call it http://xyz.com/mynetwork/generatelink

Comment: Have you tried using routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found out why it didn't work - the problem was with areas. If the controller is in a different area, this needs to be specified:

```
@Url.Action("About", "Home", new { area = ""}, Request.Url.Scheme)
```

In my case, the view was in MyNetwork area, and the controller wasn't inside an area at all - so I used empty string.

Got the answer thanks to this one: [Url.Action doesnt work with non standard MVC Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649726/url-action-doesnt-work-with-non-standard-mvc-route)